# Rapid-fire Community Wiki edits; how should this be handled?

Tags: discussion, edits, community-wiki

I spotted [an older community wiki question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c?answertab=active#tab-top) suddenly pop up in the active tab and started poking around to see what changed.

From what I can tell, it's a single user making extremely minor edits to many of the answers, most of which have a very low vote count:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13713420/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24964916/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27512317/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/236158/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13713420/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29007199/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18151541/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27125803/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23486832/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11652347/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8457004/revisions
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22460128/revisions

(The edits keep coming but I feel like I've listed enough here)

How should this be handled?  Should the edits be rolled back?
I'd normally vote "too minor", but the edits don't offer me the ability to review them.  They seem to have already been applied.

Comment: You may flag for moderator attention to stop a single user making too minor edits in series just to gain rep.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Do I flag the answer or the edit itself?  I don't seem to have the ability to flag the edit, just source/edit/link.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Just flag one of the edited posts

Comment: You make the problem clear in flagging the edited post. The moderators have access to the edit history as anyone else has.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can already hear it: *I just wanted to improve the answer* groan.  You have to love those people which change 2 characters and say that they just wanted to improve the post

Comment: For the record, the whole thread is Community Wiki, so there are no suggested edits. The 1.8k user can make an edit with no reviewers.

Comment: Mr. Llama and @πάνταῥεῖ, just to point out, though the user has less than 2k rep, these are not _suggested edits_ and therefore the user gains no rep from them due to _all of the answers_ being Community Wiki, which anyone with any amount of rep can edit without being reviewed.

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't believe them unless they have more than 2k rep.

Comment: @Kendra Good point, I didn't spot this.

Comment: @Kendra - Does that change how the situation should be handled?  On a side note, do edits on community wiki questions count towards badges?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Kinda right, but I still see a few people which are clearly hunting for the: Illuminator badge. And they change like a tag or so and then do a rollback or something stupid like this. Always fun to watch :)

Comment: I would say it does change how the situation should be handled. As it's all on one question, only _one_ question is being bumped by the edits. While it may get annoying to see the same question over and over again, it's far better than seeing dozens of old, inactive questions being bumped. I would say comment on one of the answers, pinging the editor, and explain that they should slow down on the edits as they are bumping the post. No need to involve a mod at this stage. No, community wiki edits do not count towards badges.

Comment: A note on pinging the editor: While the name will not auto-populate when you start to ping the editor, it will still notify them if you manually type out their name.

Comment: The user appears to have stopped now. Because the post is CW, the only thing they achieved is (negative) attention to their actions, no reputation is gained for the edits.

Comment: It seems someone has been really busy making minor edits on the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/29932159#29932159) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript/24460952#24460952) question as well

Comment: It should be noted that [I was wrong about community wiki edits counting towards badges.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) Seems I remembered ever so slightly wrong. Either way, all fixed now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up, we have dealt with the user; they appeared to be trying to game the editing badges.

In future, feel free to flag such a post for moderator intervention and explain that a user appears to be making loads of minor edits to CW posts, and we'll take a look if an intervention is needed.

Comment: @TravisJ: once moderators were looking at the account we found other things beyond the editing that were of a more serious nature. The suspension was not handed out for the edits.

Comment: Just an outsider looking in ;) Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, What does `voting irregularities.` mean? Or this cant be disclosed?

Comment: @ShaunakD: just that. Voting that doesn't comply with the site rules (i.e. fraud, targeted voting, etc.).